# Is a WSDL similar to a Java Interface?

Tags: java, interface

If I should explain a java interface or an abstract class with only abstract methods to someone and the person knows what a WSDL is for, would the WSDL be a good analogy for the java interface?

My idea to explain this is the following:

A caller can get a WSDL from a service provider and is hence able to create the methods in order to call the service provider with the right signatures. Similar getting an interface as a caller from another party on your project which implements the interface in their classes shows you how to call certain methods of other objects.

On the hand, a caller could determine how the service provider should be called. In order to do that the caller would give a WSDL to the service provider so that the service provider creates the methods with certain method names and parameters on which the service provider gets called. Same could be done with an interface: the caller gives the interface to someone who implements the interface in order to get called the way the caller needs it to be.

Is that idea correct or am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything, the gist of both is the same: they represent a contract that serves to decouple the caller from the implementor. They both *describe* a service. But Java interfaces and WSDLs obviously work on very different levels - the former is simply a contract the implementing classes (that can implement multiple interfaces) must comply with, while the other is a language-agnostic contract for an entire set of services accessed over a network.
Look up *contract first* development and you'll realize there are many many more piece of technology that essentially serve this same purpose.